# how will you be replace the bad disk ( predective error disk ) which contains data?

Tags: aix

In one of the VG having 5 PVs, one of the PV got predective error, so finally  decided to replace that disk.    Now how will you be replace the bad disk ( predective error disk ) which contains data?

Comment: Probably better asked on [Unix.se]

Answer (score 0):

Ah...  I'm not a file system / LVM type guy and I was puzzled by your question.  This [page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1000426) gave me the clues I needed.

You add a new disk to the volume group (VG).  And then you migrate the data from the bad PV off.  You should have space to do this since you just added a new PV.  Now, remove the bad PV from the VG.

I've not personally done this recently but I believe I have done it.  There should be links on how to do each step.  In fact, this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/migcontpv.htm) is probably easier to follow and more complete.